# How to populate a parameter file on bitbucket pipelines

Tags: symfony, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

I have to populate a parameters.yml file with variables in my pipeline. This is about 60 lines required in the file. So I tried using about 60 echo statements to populate the file, and keep it easily configurable, but when using the validator, it says my pipelines file is invalid because I need to use either a string or a pipe.

Is there another option that would let me echo a multi-line string to a file, or an other option to populate that file with environment variables?

This is how I tried it now:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: install and test
        caches:
          - composer
          - node
          - vendor
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm install -g gulp
          - echo "parameters:" > app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    database_driver: pdo_mysql" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    database_host: $DB_HOST" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    database_port: $DB_PORT" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    database_name: $DB_NAME" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    database_user: $DB_USER" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    database_password: $DB_PASS" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    redis.dsn.cache: \"$REDIS\"/0" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    redis.dsn.doctrine: \"$REDIS/1\"" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    redis.dsn.session: \"$REDIS/2\"" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    mailer_transport: $MAIL_TRANSPORT" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    mailer_host: $MAIL_HOST" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    mailer_user: $MAIL_USER" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    mailer_password: $MAIL_PASS" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    mailer_port: $MAIL_PORT" >> app/config/parameters.yml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the validator had some issues with me echo-ing yaml in the configuration. This is how I fixed it:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: install and test
        caches:
          - composer
          - node
          - vendor
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm install -g gulp
          - echo "parameters:" > app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    database_driver:\ pdo_mysql" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    database_host:\ $DB_HOST" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    database_port:\ $DB_PORT" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    database_name:\ $DB_NAME" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    database_user:\ $DB_USER" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    database_password:\ $DB_PASS" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    redis.dsn.cache:\ \"$REDIS/0\"" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    redis.dsn.doctrine:\ \"$REDIS/1\"" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    redis.dsn.session:\ \"$REDIS/2\"" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    mailer_transport:\ $MAIL_TRANSPORT" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    mailer_host:\ $MAIL_HOST" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    mailer_user:\ $MAIL_USER" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    mailer_password:\ $MAIL_PASS" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - echo "    mailer_port:\ $MAIL_PORT" >> app/config/parameters.yml
          - sed -i 's/\\ / /g' app/config/parameters.yml
```

Basically I couldn't echo valid yaml, so I fixed it using sed to modify the file so the yaml became valid.